How can I find all Azure app registrations with API permissions to a specific app registration?
I have an app registration in Azure that exposes an API (let's say the app id is 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001)
There are many app registrations in our tenant that have been granted access to the app roles/user scopes of this app.
How can I find all app registrations in my tenant that have been granted API permissions for this app?
If I go to a specific app that I know has been provided access, I can see in the manifest that it is listed under requiredResourceAccess.resourceAppId.
e.g. 

I'm looking for a way to find all apps that have been given access to this app.
I don't really care if the solution is PowerShell, MS Graph, Azure UI, etc.
Thanks!

I have one Azure app registration named APIapp that exposes an API as below:

For sample, I granted this permission to few applications that displays below resourceAppId in App's Manifest:

To list all app registrations that have been granted API permissions for this app, you can make use of below sample PowerShell script:
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "Application.Read.All"

# Define the App ID of the target app
$appId = "07323297-dbd0-xxxxxxxx"

$allApps = Get-MgApplication -All
$filteredApps = $allApps | Where-Object {
    $_.RequiredResourceAccess.ResourceAppId -contains $appId
}

$filteredApps

Response:


This worked perfectly, thank you!

Glad to be of help : )
